# How to set ItemSource and ItemTemplate to display a list of objects

Tags: wpf, list, data-binding, mvvm, itemtemplate

I have a List box that I want to display a list of objects, I am following the MVVM pattern and am finding it difficult to achieve what I want.

MainWindowView.xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
    private List<ListBoxItem> _myList = new List<ListBoxItem>();

    public List<ListBoxItem> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList ; }
        set
        {
            _myList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyList");
        }
    }

    public SprintBacklogViewModel()
    {
        foreach(MyObject obj in MyObjects.MyObjectList)
        {
            ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
            item.Content = obj;
            MyList.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

MyList is getting updated correctly, but nothing is displaying in the window. *(ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}" also works, I tested with different data)* I have not used an ItemTemplate before so any pointers are welcome. My understanding of it is that If I set it up correctly It will display the data in my objects. 
eg:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
```

there is a property in MyObject called Name, I want to display this as a label in my list

*EDIT
In my window I get a line of text - mynamespace.MyObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyList property in ViewModel is property of type [ListBoxItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611063.aspx), it has property [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx) but it's not Name of MyObject. So you need to change your property in your ViewModel by

**Replace**

```
private List<ListBoxItem> _myList = new List<ListBoxItem>();

public List<ListBoxItem> MyList
{
    get { return _myList ; }
    set
    {
        _myList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyList");
    }
}
```

**with**

```
private List<MyObject> _myList = new List<MyObject>();

public List<MyObject> MyList
{
    get { return _myList ; }
    set
    {
        _myList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyList");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your list should not contain UI-Elements but data (you are **data**-binding), if you bind to a list of `ListBoxItems` the `ListBox` will disregard the `ItemTemplate` and just use the items as they fit the expected container for the `ListBox`. Containers will be generated automatically, you do not need to do that in your list.
2. If you add items to a collection at runtime the binding engine needs to be notified to update the changes, for this you should use an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) or anything that implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx). *(When doing so you further usually make the field `readonly` and only provide a getter)* This is the reason why there are no items.